# CSS Percentage Horizontal Padding Not Relative to Element After Achieving Max Width?

Tags: html, css, padding, viewport

I'm working on my new portfolio site (http://www.marcial.is) and I'm baffled by a padding issue that I can't explain. The way I’m structuring the layout is that each row of content comprises of an outer wrapper and an inner wrapper. For example:

```
<header class="global-header" role="banner">
    <div class="header-inner">...</div>
</header>
```

The outer wrapper is 100% wide. The inner wrapper has a max-width, centered with margin auto. The inner wrapper also has a percentage of padding to allow me to kick in content as I see on each row (such as the header example above). Here's an example of my SCSS to illustrate:

```
.global-header {
    background: #007bc4;
    text-align: center;
    text-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(#000, 0.2);
    border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(#000, 0.15);
    padding: 1.25em 0.625em 2.5em;
    @include at-break($breakMedium) {
        padding: 3.125em 1.25em 6.25em;
    }
    @include at-break($breakLarge) {
        padding: 3.125em $gutter 6.25em;
    }
}

.header-inner {
    max-width: $maxWidth; 
    margin: 0 auto;
    @include at-break($breakSmall) {
        margin: 0 18.181818181818%;
    }
    @include at-break($breakMedium) {
        margin: 0 11.764705882353%;
    }
    @include at-break($breakLarge) {
        margin: 0 17.391304347826%;
    }
}
```

The problem is that percentage padding on the inner wrapper seems to continue to increase, despite the inner wrapper having already hit the applied max-width. Why would the padding of the inner wrapper continue to increase with the viewport width if the max-width has been achieved?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Why would the padding of the inner wrapper continue to increase with the viewport width if the max-width has been achieved?

Because, http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/box.html#padding-properties:

> The percentage is calculated with respect to the width of the generated box's **containing block**, […]

Your outer `div` provides the [containing block](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visuren.html#containing-block) here.

You will need to use an additional element inside `.header-inner` here, and apply the padding to *that*, so that the `.header-inner` that has the `max-width` set becomes the containing block for that inner element.

Comment: Thanks, dude. I somehow had always assumed that padding was relative to the element it was applied to and not its parent. Appreciate you setting me straight.